# ALTER vs DROP & CREATE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

After creating stored procedure in SQL Server why to replace `Create` with `Alter`? What will happen on execution if we do not change it? Is there a better alternate to it other then checking if exist and drop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Create` will fail if table exists. `Alter` will fail if table does not exist.

If you ask why to use `Alter` if you can drop and create, a few reasons:

- certain permissions already assigned to the object, you would need to regrant permissions if you drop it
- object is probably used by other objects with schema binding

Comment: FYI: stored procs don't support schemabinding unfortunately

Comment: @gbn - oops, you are right, would make sense for functions though.

Comment: Yep. I always use [schemabinding](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A27535+schemabinding). I *wish* stored procs had it too. http://www.sommarskog.se/strict_checks.html#killDNR and http://www.sommarskog.se/wishlist.html

Comment: +1. I would also add that ALTER preserves extended properties. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243.aspx Some ORM tools and designer make use of extended properties.

Comment: In my case, when I try to Alter Proc it tells me "Invalid object name XXXXX" then when I use Create Proc, it works and change back to Alter, it is still working ... anyone can explain why ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no "CREATE OR REPLACE" syntax in SQL Server (like in other RDBMS)

I tend to use this pattern if I'm unsure that something exists.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyProc') IS NOT NULL
   DROP PROC dbo.MyProc
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.MyProc
...
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ---
GO
```

Comment: I like doing this too. The problem is that sometimes schema and permissions are managed by different parties.

Comment: @Alex Aza: yep, we actually use and permission schemas so objects inherit of course and we don't have object level permissions. However, when someone asks question like this then they don't tend to have such separation of concerns etc

Answer (score 1):

From my learnings,

- Whenever you provide a database build, It is a good practice to check if Stored Procedure exists to drop and then recreate the procedure.
- Changing from create to alter might happen while debugging the procedure but this is not a standard practice while providing build.

Answer (score 1):

On the topic of helpful scripts I prefer to create the procedure if not exists and then alter it instead.

```
IF (select object_ID('schema.Procedure')) is null
    exec('Create procedure schema.Procedure as select 1')
GO

Alter procedure dpm.TableCellLoad
```

This way priviligies granted to the procedure will always remain and if the procedure did not exist it is created.